# Почему to_datetime неправильно форматирует дату?

Tags: python, pandas

Столкнулся с непонятной ситуацией. При форматировании даты происходит замена месяца на дни и наоборот:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['11.08.2020']})
df
```

Получаем таблицу:

```
         col1
-------------
0  11.08.2020
```

Теперь форматирую её:

```
df = pd.to_datetime(df.col1)
df
```

И вот, что получается:

```
0   2020-11-08
Name: col1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

11 августа превратилась в 8 октября!!!
Такое же происходит и  с 12 мая, превращается в 5 декабря. Может быть и с другими датами такое же случается.
Как с эти бороться и как можно проверить правильно ли форматируются другие даты?

Comment: `.to_datetime(df.col1, dayfirst=True)`

Comment: @ entithat Спасибо, вроде решилась проблема!

Comment: Можно еще так: `.to_datetime(df.col1, format='%d.%m.%Y')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@entithat помог решить:

```
df = pd.to_datetime(df.col1, dayfirst=True)
```

```
0   2020-08-11
Name: col1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```